# Can you invite friends to a group build in ROBLOX?

Tags: building, roblox

people take long when they build places alone on ROBLOX but if we invite friends to a group build it will be faster process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the group building feature in groups to build together with friends. It will all save in that group's place. This is a very untested feature, and its development has ground to a halt due to other updates taking priority. It should work fine for simply building, though.

You can also join building places and build together, although you won't be able to save anything to your own place.

Hope this helps!

-pighead10

Comment: please do not post signatures on stack overflow as your name is displayed about 100 pixels to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can build with friends at your group's place (if you have permission). Roblox does not have the feature to invite friends to group building yet! Maybe you should suggest inviteing friends to the admins. Maybe it will be made because of you!

Hope this helped!

-Bodesjr

Answer (score 0):

There *could* be a new feature that lets you build in your main places with your **best friends** only.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily invite, but they could join, if they have BC, TBS, OBC.

Answer (score 0):

You set the permissions in Group Admin; give you're friends the admin rank and they will have edit.